# How do I set a crosshair to appear on the screen of a game that doesn't have crosshairs?

Tags: pc

If you know about third-person shooters, some of them don't have a crosshair and you have to predict where you shoot. Some people use transparent tape with a marker dot to aim and I do that too, it's funny I know.

Is there a software solution to have a crosshair or a dot, appear on the screen of a game that doesn't have crosshairs?

Comment: Any game or games in particular ?

Comment: If you're playing a TPS with the "dot" (though invisible) always in the same spot, what exactly do you want to adjust? And over-ride *what* in the game? Also - questions about "How do I code (something)?" would be more StackOverflow's or GameDev's topic.

Comment: Its Soldier of Fortune 2 - Though its a first person shooter, its played in 3rd person as well. And I basically want a dot to appear in the game just a bit above center of the screen where a crosshair usually is. With over-riding I mean that if you run a program along with a game, its possible that the game's screen hides the background dot behind it so I mean to say that the cross should stay above all running application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build a small Lego construction to hold a laser pointer and position it such that it marks the "aiming point" on your screen.

[image]

With a slightly more complex set-up you can also make a Blutooth-controllable one, so you can even adjust the position directly with your computer.

[image]

Images and idea from [this thread on the Laser Pointer Forums](http://laserpointerforums.com/f48/lego-laser-turrets-43464.html)

Comment: Looks good but it's more of a hardware setup while my thing can easily be done at software level.

Comment: @AsadMoeen: Never underestimate the power of hardware hacks. :) The software solution is called "screen overlay", you might want to google that too, in particular "directx screen overlay" or similar.

Comment: Yeah that's great and best in fact but requires some money haha.

Answer (score 0):

I remember i did one a long time ago as a cheat to counterstrike for sniper weapons that did not display cross when not in scope mode.

Heres how i did:

Download free version of game maker, set the room to be very few pixels, set stayontop to true, disable windows border and set background to some strong color. Make a object and in creation code set window x position to half screen width and y to half height.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, try something like:

```
echo -e "+" |osd_cat -p middle -A center -d 0 -f '-*-helvetica-*-r-*-*-26-*-*-*-*-*-*-*' -O 1 -c '#f00' -o -70 -i 1
```

or

```
echo -e "+" |osd_cat -p middle -A center -d 0 -f '-*-helvetica-*-r-*-*-11-*-*-*-*-*-*-*' -O 1 -c '#0f0' -o -32 -i 1
```

Type `osd_cat --help` for a list of options.